# How To Get Around FacesContext Being Null In Seperate Servlet - JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, servlets, facesservlet

I am trying to internationalize my web application, so I am using a ResourceBundle and dynamically changing the locale using:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
```

Which worked fine at first. But I am trying to use an AJAX call to update the page, and the program uses a third party servlet to handle the AJAX calls. So now when my bean gets called, it keeps getting a null exception (since I am not in the FacesServlet, I'm in some other servlet).

The code to call the ajax looks like

```
<revit:button id="ajaxMe" type="button" 
  onClick="primeAjaxCall();localeCodeChanged();">Select Language</revit:button>
    <revit:ajax method="#{stringbean.localeCodeChanged}"
     call="localeCodeChanged" callback="ajaxCallback" postData="parameter" />
```

The managed bean code:

```
public AJAXResponse localeCodeChanged(Map<String, String[]> parameterMap, Map<String, String> headers)
{
    // read in the parameters to get the locale

    // how can I effectively call this without null pointer?
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` will be `null` if the request is not attended by `FacesServlet`, which seems to be your case. I would recommend not refreshing the page through ajax.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, yes I know why it is null, but is there another way to refresh page without reloading?